# Python Recursive Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, class, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to recursively implement a binary search tree in python, using a Node class and Tree class.

```
# MAKE CUSTOM ERROS
class Error(Exception):
    pass

class InvalidKeyError(Error):
    pass

# TREE NODE CLASS
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, inKey, inValue): # eahc node has a key with an associated value
        self._key = inKey
        self._value = inValue
        self._left = None
        self._right = None

    def __str__(self): # Used for printing
        return ("Key: " + str(self._key) + " Value: " + str(self._value))

# SEARCH TREE CLASS
class BinarySearchTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None # start with an empty tree

    # Wrapper method
    def find(self, key):
        return self._findRec(key, self._root)

    def _findRec(self, key, cur):
        value = None
        if cur == None:
            raise InvalidKeyError("Key " + str(key) + " not found")
        elif key == cur._key: # Base case: found
            value = cur._value
        elif key < cur._key: # goes left
            value = self._findRec(key, cur._left)
        else: # goes right
            value = self._findRec(key, cur._right)
        return value

    # Wrapper method
    def insert(self, key, data):
        return self._insertRec(key, data, self._root)

    def _insertRec(self, key, data, cur):
        updateNode = cur
        if cur == None:
            updateNode = TreeNode(key, data)
        elif key == cur._key: # in the tree
            raise InvalidKeyError("Key " + str(key) + " is already in the tree")
        elif key < cur._key:
            cur._left = self._insertRec(key, data, cur._left)
        else:
            cur._right = self._insertRec(key, data, cur._right)
        return updateNode
    
# TESTING
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myTree = BinarySearchTree()
    myTree.insert(9, "nine")
    myTree.insert(5, "five")
    myTree.insert(13, "thirteen")

    print(myTree.find(13))
```

I don't receive any errors when inserting keys/values into my tree but I receive an error when attempting to find nodes in the tree.
*InvalidKeyError: Key 13 not found*

Is there a logic error in my insert method? Thank you!

Comment: The error is getting thrown from line 31 **raise InvalidKeyError("Key " + str(key) + " not found")** If you look at the immediately preceding line you will see why.

Comment: Either the tree isn't getting built correctly, or you aren't searching it correctly.  I'd start by writing a function to output the entire tree so you can figure out if it's getting built correctly.

Comment: The PROBLEM here is that you never set `self._root`.  It is always None, so the `find` fails first thing.  A few debug prints would have shown you that.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive insert thing can't work.  By the time you notice that your node is empty, you no longer have a thing to modify.  This seems to work:

```
    def _insertRec(self, key, data, cur):
        newnode = TreeNode(key, data)
        if not self._root:
            self._root = newnode
            return

        while key != cur._key:
            if key < cur._key:
                if not cur._left:
                    cur._left = newnode
                    return
                cur = cur._left
            else:
                if not cur._right:
                    cur._right = newnode
                    return
                cur = cur._right
                
        raise InvalidKeyError("Key " + str(key) + " is already in the tree")
```